# sql group where clause

Tags: sql, dynamic-columns

I have a table like this:

```
| grpType | grpId  | paramId |   val |
|---------|--------|:-------:|------:|
| 0       | 81452  |   123   | 1,293 |
| 0       | 81452  |   127   |    46 |
| 2       | 19873  |   282   |     3 |
| 2       | 19873  |   283   | -10,3 |
| 3       | 81455  |   123   | 1,144 |
| 3       | 100379 |   178   |    40 |
| 3       | 100379 |   188   |   269 |
| 3       | 100379 |   189   |   298 |
| 3       | 100379 |   190   |   267 |
| 3       | 100379 |   191   |   278 |
| 1       | 256    |   188   |   419 |
| 1       | 256    |   189   |   433 |
| 1       | 256    |   190   |   434 |
| 1       | 256    |   191   |   429 |
```

I want to get data from this table with conditions such as "paramId = 123 and val> = 1.2", "paramId=188 and val<=269", "paramId=189 and val>=298".

Here, since the conditions of "paramId = 188 and val <=269" and "paramId = 189 and val >298" have the same "grpId" in the table, both conditions specified for the "Val" column should provide. In the table above, There are 2 groups that meet the "paramId = 188, paramId = 189" condititon. I have to get the group that provides the requirement of "paramId = 188 and val <=269" and "paramId = 189 and val >298".(so the group of 100379 id)

However, the rows that provide the third condition (paramId = 123 and val >= 1.2) should be added to the data. In the table above, there are two "paramId = 123" row. I have to get the row that provides the requirement of "val >= 1.2".

The "grpType" column is not an important column. You can ignore.
I just need a distinct "grpID" list.

How should the query be I will write?

Comment: Also _specify_ the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

You can write combination of these conditions use `OR` in where condition.

```
Select *
from <TableName>
where ((paramId = 123 and Val >= 1.2) or (paramid=188 and Val <= 269) or (paramid=189 and Val <= 298))
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Because some groups have multiple parameters. In this case, if the group has that parameter, the conditions should be met together.

Comment: what does mean This doesn't work ? In that case you need to post you question with correct details.

Comment: There are two groups with 188 and 189 "paramId". (100379, 256)
Our conditions are as follows: (Paramid = 188 and Val <= 269) and (Paramid = 189 and Val > = 298)
These conditions are not separate, you need to think together. Group 100379 provides this. The group 256 only provides the (paramid = 189 and val >= 298) condition, not the other.

Comment: How Paramid is 188 & 189. It should be either this or that. it can't be 188 & 189. I Can only give closer solution and I can't `think together` for your exact solution.

Comment: Parameters belonging to the same group in the conditions must be together, but if they belong to different groups, they can be separate. I know it's very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

It's like a query will work. If I use intersect, I can't get the rows itself. I can only get common data. It's enough for me now. The number of rows in this table is over 3 million and is constantly increasing. I'm a little worried about performance. I will continue the research.

```
(select grpId from tableX where paramId=51 and val>=600
intersect
select grpId from tableX where paramId=52 and val<15)

union

(select grpId  from tableX where paramId=188 and val<= 269
intersect
select grpId from tableX where paramId=189 and val<= 298)

union

select grpId from tableX where paramId=123 and val<1.29
```